# How to map a self-reference in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate-mapping

I have a very special NHibernate mapping case. The class has a reference to itself.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public MyClass SelfReference { get; set; }
}
```

The data base table has a foreign key field on the primary key of the same table. And event worse, this self reference can be null.

Is that possible to map and how can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one-to-one can be used to synchronize primary keys and is used rarely, in my experience many-to-one is the most "natural" association for "normal" references:

```
<many-to-one name="SelfReference" class="MyClass" column="SelfReference_FK" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you're willing to map a tree:

http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/16/how-to-map-a-tree-in-nhibernate

Comment: Can NHibernate map only one many-to-one relationship? Usually you allways need both sites.

Comment: You can map the other end as well.
You'll have to ends:
a one-to-many which contains the children of the current node
a one-to-one which refers to the parent of the current node

Comment: the link is broken, can you fix it ?

Comment: Wayback archive link to above post
https://web.archive.org/web/20120107071115/http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/16/how-to-map-a-tree-in-nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you'd just treat it the same as any other one-to-one relationship?

Answer (score 0):

i think its a simple one-to-one.

i hope this will help u

```
<one-to-one
name="PropertyName"
class="ClassName"
cascade="all|none|save-update|delete"
constrained="true|false"
fetch="join|select"
property-ref="PropertyNameFromAssociatedClass"
access="field|property|nosetter|ClassName"/>
```